# Mongoose alternative to SQL SELECT field, COUNT(field) FROM db

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a mongoose function in order to find a field value and the amount of times it exists in the document.

For example:

```
"Info": {
    "fullName": "full name",
    "address": "address",
    "city": "city",
    "pcode": "PostCode",
    "dob": "01/01/2022",
    "bin": "411111"
  },

"Info": {
    "fullName": "full name",
    "address": "address",
    "city": "city",
    "pcode": "PostCode",
    "dob": "01/01/2022",
    "bin": "411111"
  },

"Info": {
    "fullName": "full name",
    "address": "address",
    "city": "city",
    "pcode": "PostCode",
    "dob": "01/01/2022",
    "bin": "411111"
  },

"Info": {
    "fullName": "full name",
    "address": "address",
    "city": "city",
    "pcode": "PostCode",
    "dob": "01/01/2022",
    "bin": "400000"
  },
```

I need the function to return something like:

bin: 411111, count: 3
bin: 400000, count: 1

Comment: Look into using `$group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation pipeline to achieve exactly what you want:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Info.bin",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```